# ¿Cómo habilitar conexiones remotas en SQLServer?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Tengo un problema en Visual Studio 2015 con C# y SQL Server(Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17230.0).

El caso es el siguiente:

- Hice un Web Service para hacer una consulta a una base de datos en mi máquina local, donde el usuario **prueba** y la contraseña **123** es un login creado en sql server(Autentificación con SQLServer). Lo siguiente es el método para traer los datos:

[image: Metodo de la consulta]

- Cuando corro el programa (en Google Chrome) para ver los datos de la base de datos me da el siguiente el error cuando intenta llenar el Dataset.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - El equipo remoto rechazó la conexión de red.)**

- Ya he intentado lo siguiente:

  1. La autentificación con el usuario **prueba** y la contraseña funciona correctamente y me permite hacer querys con el mismo.
  2. Ya intente cambiar el nombre del Data Source, indicando mi instancia, por ejemplo:  **SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-0BSC7D1\SQLEXPRESS,1433;Initial Catalog=ControlGastos1;User Id=prueba;Password=123");**
  3. Ya fui a **SQLServer**->**Security**->**Logins**->**Properties**(del usuario prueba)->**Securables** y habilité algunas opciones que indicaban sobre conexión(Connect SQL, Control Server).
  4. Habilité las dos opciones de **Named Pipes** y **TCP/IP** que se encuentran en **Sql Server Configuration Manager**->**SQL Server Network Configuration**->**Protocols for SQLEXPRESS**
  5. En el **Data Source** intente ponerle mi IP de la máquina ya que en otro equipo me funcionaba colocarle la IP sin indicarle la instancia

Gracias por la ayuda con que la que me podría brindar.

Comment: Hola amigo, mmm lo logro entender a lo que indicas con lo del archivo udp

Comment: Ya lo hice, me abrió las propiedades normales de una archivo, necesito tener alguna herramienta en especifico para abrir el archivo?

Comment: PERDON.. mi error.. vamos de vuelta.. crea el archivo .udl (mala mia).. dale doble click, y de ahi podes probar la conexion y ver que cadena funciona

Comment: Probaste cambiar la dirección del servidor?, es decir en lugar de pasar el nombre del host, prueba pasar la dirección ip en la cadena de conexión

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos, ya logré resolver el problema. El puerto era el problema, utilicé el que viene por default.

Answer (score 5):

[¿Cómo configuro SQL Server Express para permitir conexiones remotas tcp / ip en el puerto 1433?](http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx) (Traducir del Ingles).

1. Ejecute el Administrador de configuración de SQL Server.
2. Vaya a Configuración de red de SQL Server> Protocolos para SQLEXPRESS.
3. Asegúrese de que TCP / IP esté habilitado.

Luego haga lo siguiente:

1. Haga clic derecho en TCP / IP y seleccione **Propiedades**.
2. Verifique que, en IP2, la Dirección IP esté configurada en la dirección IP de la computadora en la subred local.
3. Desplázate hacia abajo hasta IPAll.
4. Asegúrese de que **TCP Dynamic Ports** esté en **blanco** . (El mío se estableció en un número de puerto de 5 dígitos).
5. Asegúrese de que el puerto **TCP** esté configurado en **1433** . (El mío estaba en blanco.)

(También, si usted sigue estos pasos, es que no es necesario para permitir Explorador de SQL Server, y sólo es necesario para permitir el puerto 1433, no 1434.)

Estos cinco pasos adicionales son algo que no recuerdo haber tenido que hacer nunca en una versión anterior de SQL Server, Express u otro. Parecen haber sido necesarios porque estoy usando una instancia con nombre (myservername \ SQLEXPRESS) en el servidor en lugar de una instancia predeterminada. Mira aquí:

[Configurar un servidor para escuchar en un puerto TCP específico (Administrador de configuración de SQL Server)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-a-server-to-listen-on-a-specific-tcp-port?view=sql-server-2017) (Traducir del Ingles).

> Fuente: [Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278115/8933039) por [Ryan Lundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5486/ryan-lundy)

---

La forma correcta de conectarse al servidor SQL remoto (sin abrir el puerto UDP 1434 y habilitar el navegador del servidor SQL) es usar **ip** y **puerto** en lugar de la **instancia con nombre**.

Usar ip y puerto en lugar de instancia con nombre también es más seguro, ya que reduce el área de superficie de ataque.

Tal vez 2 imágenes hablan 2000 palabras ...

**Este método usa el puerto especificado (esto es lo que la mayoría de la gente quiere, creo).**

[image]

**Este método requiere abrir el puerto UDP 1434 y el navegador SQL Server en ejecución...**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hola deberias asegurarte que el servidor tiene habilitada las conexiones remotas. prueba desde el servidor click derecho en propiedades > conexiones y en la opcion de conexiones remotas habilitar el check.