# Conexion c # a un servidor remoto

Tags: c#

Hola por favor necesito ayuda , quiero conectar mi aplicación desde el ejecutable  a un servidor que esta en otra pc estoy usando phpadmin y c #

Este es el codigo del appconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
    </startup>
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
      <add name="MySql Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"
       description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySql"
       type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version =6.9.9.0,
       Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>

    </DbProviderFactories>

  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="PDHN"
     connectionString="Server = localhost;Port=3306;Database=horarioescolar;Uid=root;Pwd='';
     charset=utf8;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta. En tu caso, no parece que exista una pregunta. Que problema estas teniendo?

Comment: entiendo quieres conectarte a una db MySql, ahora bien porque si quieres conectarte remoto en el conection string usas "localhost" ?

Comment: te conectas usando ado.net o entity framework ?

Comment: Tene en cuenta que phpadmin no es una base de datos. Es un adminitrador que te permite conectarte a una base de datos, supongo que sera mysql.

Comment: Probablemente tu error es por tratar de acceder como root desde fuera del servidor. En Mysql, hay que activar ese permiso en la base de datos manualmente. Pero como no quieres darnos el error que te da, pues son solo suposiciones :)

Comment: Ya probaste si tienes acceso con el Management Studio?, checa este post: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/158082/c%C3%B3mo-habilitar-conexiones-remotas-en-sqlserver

Comment: SI eh puesto el ip de mi servidor que es el 192.168.4.9 pero en cuanto trato de ejecutarlo desde otra maquina no me deja , la maquina si tiene conexión con el servido pero no desde la aplicación , estoy usando framework 4.5.2